# Mahjongg doesn't display scores

Tags: games

Since updating to 12.10 in mahjongg it always tells me I didn't make the top 10, but it doesn't show what the scores are. I used to following to reset the scores:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-games/+question/43471

However it still gives the same message and shows no scores. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about the confusion.  You just have to rename them by appending `gnome-` in front of their names, example - `/var/games/gnome-mahjongg.dragon.scores`

Doesn't need the permissions change.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. If I uninstalled and then reinstalled the program, it should be intelligent enough to use the correct name. I did notice at the time I removed it that the scores were erased. When they came back they were without the gnome- addition. In any case your answer is indeed correct. Thanks, Ilan

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed mine after running strace on gnome-mahjongg
/var/games/gnome-mahjongg.easy.scores was not found
they are naming them mahjongg.easy.scores so following suit I changed the permissions on the /var/games/ directory and its files inside and for added measure I created a blank file in the directory with the proper name.  Scores started saving.

Comment: /var/games/mahjongg.bridges.scores
/var/games/mahjongg.cloud.scores
/var/games/mahjongg.confounding.scores
/var/games/mahjongg.difficult.scores
/var/games/mahjongg.dragon.scores
/var/games/mahjongg.easy.scores
/var/games/mahjongg.pyramid.scores
/var/games/mahjongg.tictactoe.scores
/var/games/mahjongg.ziggurat.scores

Comment: Hi Andy, I still can't get it to fly. You can see the contents of /var/game and see that the names are correct. The permission is read and write for root and group, games. So from what you say (and from common sense as well), it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: If you look under the Mahjongg menu, you should see a scores entry. That used to display the scores but since it is empty, it displays nothing. I assume for you it will display something?